# How to match blank characters with regex in bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I need to match something like "?xml  'this is what I want'?", and get the strings between the single quotes.
I try this:

```
if [[ '?xml   abc def?' =~ \?xml(.*)\? ]]; then
    echo ok;
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}";
fi
```

result:

```
ok
   abc def
```

I just want 'abc def'. So I try:

```
if [[ '?xml    abc def?' =~ \?xml[:blank:]+(.*)\? ]]; then #nothing matched
if [[ '?xml    abc def?' =~ \?xml\[:blank:\]+(.*)\? ]]; then #nothing matched
if [[ '?xml    abc def?' =~ \?xml\s+(.*)\? ]]; then #nothing matched
```

How do I fix this?Help!

Comment: You can try `\s*`. I'm not sure whether PCRE is enabled or not. Otherwise, the `:blank:` needs to be enclosed in double square brackets like `[[:blank:]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[[:space:]]` to remove all whitespace:

```
if [[ '?xml   abc def?' =~ \?xml[[:space:]]*(.*)\? ]];
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note 2 square brackets on both ends of the bracket expression (or POSIX character class). As per the regular-expressions.info:

> **The POSIX syntax... can only be used inside a bracket expression.**
>
> `[x-z0-9]` is an example of what this tutorial calls a "character class" and what POSIX calls a "bracket expression".

See [demo](http://ideone.com/aJLQtW)

The `[:space:]` POSIX character class matches `[ \t\r\n\v\f]` characters.

See more about [POSIX character classes at regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need  to  include `[:blank:]` inside another bracket (character class).

```
$ if [[ '?xml   abc def?' =~ \?xml[[:blank:]]+(.*)\? ]]; then     echo ok;     echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; fi
ok
abc def
```